# Force character set conversion

Tags: python, character-encoding, sqlalchemy

I have an application that writes data to a Microsoft SQL Server. Database's character set is CP1252, and to-be-saved incoming data is in UTF-8. The data may contain characters that cannot be converted to CP1252, and will throw an exception when inserted.

The database guys said that I should just crunch the data to CP1252 forcibly, like this:

```
some_value = some_value.encode('CP1252', 'replace')
```

But SQLAlchemy does the conversion automatically and I don't see a way to force the conversion.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://...'
    encoding='CP1252',
    convert_unicode=True,
    )
```

It is critical that the data is saved, even with some missing characters. How can I implement this? Note that I'm using a lot of database reflection in this case.

Comment: I recommend you switch the database's encoding rather than just throwing data around and not caring where it lands and if you get it all.

Comment: Sadly the database is out of my hands, it cannot be modified in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem.

```
some_value = some_value.encode('CP1252', 'replace').decode('CP1252')
```

If `some_value` isn't actually unicode string but the raw UTF-8 data:

```
some_value = some_value.decode("utf-8").encode('cp1252', 'replace').decode('cp1252')
```

Comment: True, you could do that. I'd like to "fix" this in SQLAlchemy so that I don't have to manually convert every value everywhere in the codebase.

Comment: @eclaird I thought you said incoming data?